# Is there a canonical haskell type for "One or Both"?

Tags: haskell

I find myself needing a data structure that contains maybe an `A`, maybe a `B`, and definitely one of them. If I were to hack up a general data type for this thing, it would probably look like:

```
data OneOrBoth a b = A a | B b | AB a b

maybeA :: OneOrBoth a b -> Maybe a
maybeB :: OneOrBoth a b -> Maybe b
eitherL :: OneOrBoth a b -> Either a b -- Prefers a
eitherR :: OneOrBoth a b -> Either a b -- Prefers b
hasBoth, hasExactlyOne, hasA, hasB :: OneOrBoth a b -> Bool
```

Does this data structure have a name? Is there a canonical way to handle one-or-both structures in Haskell?

Comment: Why stop at two types?  Three, Four, ...?  :-)

Comment: If you wanted "Zero, One, or Both" you'd have `1 + A + B + A*B = (1 + A) * (1 + B)` or `(Maybe A, Maybe B)`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[`Data.These`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.3/docs/Data-These.html)

> This can be useful to represent combinations of two values, where the
>   combination is defined if either input is. Algebraically, the type
>   `These A B` represents (A + B + AB), which doesn't factor easily into
>   sums and products — a type like `Either A (B, Maybe A)` is unclear and
>   awkward to use.

Comment: Not really canonical, but definitely a better choice than rolling your own, although this package does come with a lot of dependencies and extras that may or may not be useful to OP

Comment: I'm not sure if this actualy beats rolling your own in all cases. It's sounds like the OP uses this a lot, but if this was a small thing I wouldn't want to pull in dependencies on profunctors, mtl, semigroups etc

Comment: Amused by how difficult it is to talk about proper nouns that are named after articles, I wrote up [`Acme.Whose`](https://github.com/tel/acme-whose/) which has the definite advantage of only pulling in `strict` and `bifunctors`. Please don't use it.

Comment: Precisely the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Data.These has been mentioned, and is probably the best choice, but if I were to roll my own, I'd do it as:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))

type These a b = Either (Either a b) (a, b)

maybeA :: These a b -> Maybe a
maybeA (Left (Left a)) = Just a
maybeA (Right (a, _))  = Just a
maybeA _               = Nothing

maybeB :: These a b -> Maybe b
maybeB (Left (Right b)) = Just b
maybeB (Right (_, b))   = Just b
maybeB _                = Nothing

eitherA :: These a b -> Either a b
eitherA (Left (Left a))  = Left a
eitherA (Right (a, _))   = Left a
eitherA (Left (Right b)) = Right b

eitherB :: These a b -> Either a b
eitherB (Left (Right b)) = Right b
eitherB (Right (_, b))   = Right b
eitherB (Left (Left a))  = Left a

hasBoth, hasJustA, hasJustB, hasA, hasB :: These a b -> Bool

hasBoth (Right _) = True
hasBoth _         = False

hasJustA (Left (Left _)) = True
hasJustA _               = False

hasJustB (Left (Right _)) = True
hasJustB _                = False

hasA = (||) <$> hasBoth <*> hasJustA
hasB = (||) <$> hasBoth <*> hasJustB
```

Answer (score 5):

If you wanted "Zero, One, or Both" you'd have `1 + A + B + A*B = (1 + A) * (1 + B)` or `(Maybe A, Maybe B)`.

You could do `A + B + A*B = (1+A)*(1+B)-1` by wrapping `(Maybe A, Maybe B)` in a `newtype` and using smart constructors to remove the `(Nothing,Nothing)`:

```
module Some (
  Some(),
  this, that, those, some,
  oror, orro, roro, roor,
  swap
) where

import Control.Applicative ((<|>))

newtype Some a b = Some (Maybe a, Maybe b) deriving (Show, Eq)

-- smart constructors
this :: a -> Some a b
this a = Some (Just a,Nothing)

that :: b -> Some a b
that b = Some (Nothing, Just b)

those :: a -> b -> Some a b
those a b = Some (Just a, Just b)

-- catamorphism/smart deconstructor
some :: (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> (a -> b -> r) -> Some a b -> r
some f _ _ (Some (Just a, Nothing)) = f a
some _ g _ (Some (Nothing, Just b)) = g b
some _ _ h (Some (Just a, Just b))  = h a b
some _ _ _ _ = error "this case should be unreachable due to smart constructors"

swap :: Some a b -> Some b a
swap ~(Some ~(ma,mb)) = Some (mb,ma)

-- combining operators
oror, orro, roro, roor :: Some a b -> Some a b -> Some a b

-- prefer the leftmost A and the leftmost B
oror (Some (ma,mb)) (Some (ma',mb')) = Some (ma <|> ma', mb <|> mb')
-- prefer the leftmost A and the rightmost B
orro (Some (ma,mb)) (Some (ma',mb')) = Some (ma <|> ma', mb' <|> mb)
-- prefer the rightmost A and the rightmost B
roro = flip oror
-- prefer the rightmost A and the leftmost B
roor = flip orro
```

The combining operators are fun:

```
λ this "red" `oror` that "blue" `oror` those "beige" "yellow"
Some (Just "red",Just "blue")
λ this "red" `orro` that "blue" `orro` those "beige" "yellow"
Some (Just "red",Just "yellow")
λ this "red" `roor` that "blue" `roor` those "beige" "yellow"
Some (Just "beige",Just "blue")
λ this "red" `roro` that "blue" `roro` those "beige" "yellow"
Some (Just "beige",Just "yellow")
```

Comment: While the algebraic factoring method is nice, I don't see how this actually provides any advantage over simply rolling your own sum type. Using a `newtype` is basically isomorphic and now pattern matching is gone.