# Combined type = one, the other, or both?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I'm wondering if this is possible in Haskell:

```
type DateTime = Date | Time | Date :+ Time
```

...so that it can be either a specific date, a specific time or a complex value made up of both.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there a canonical haskell type for “One or Both”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19413438/1333025)

Comment: To cut to the punchline: [`Data.These`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.3/docs/Data-These.html)

Comment: BTW, “bundling a `Date` and a `Time` value together” is actually the _product_ of both types, not the sum. As an ADT, what you want is written `DateTime = Date + Time + Date × Time`, or, in Haskell, `Either (Either Date Time) (Date, Time)`. However, it is better to define the type with `data` like AJFarmar did, or to use `These`.

Comment: I was thinking of a `Time` as an imaginary `Date` (`Time = Date × sqrt(-1)`) : P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just made it - of course it's possible!

Here's what I would make it:

```
data Both a b
    = First a
    | Second b
    | Both a b
```

Interestingly, this is a bifunctor:

```
import Data.Bifunctor

instance Bifunctor Both where
    bimap f _ (First a)  = First (f a)
    bimap _ g (Second b) = Second (g b)
    bimap f g (Both a b) = Both (f a) (g b)
```

As [J. Abrahamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476408/j-abrahamson) said, there is a type called `These` in the package [`Data.These`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.3/docs/Data-These.html), which includes `Monad` and `Bifunctor` instances, as well as some awesome typeclass instances like `Bifoldable` and `Bitraversable` that are totally worth having a peek at.

Comment: The problem with recursive representation of datetime thing, that it can potentially have more than one recursion level, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What do you mean by recursive?

Comment: Can a `Both a b` include a `Both (Both a b) (Both a b)`? looks like `data Tree a b = Leaf a | Leaf b | Tree a b`.

Comment: @Mark Cidade `a` and `b` can stand for any type - why not? But that Tree type is a little off, have another go!