# Mandatory Maybes in the type system

Tags: haskell

I have something similar to the following

```
data A = A
  { id :: Integer
  , foo :: Maybe String
  , bar :: Maybe String
  , baz :: Maybe String
  }
```

This data is coming in to my service as JSON. This request is only considered valid when one or more of `foo`, `bar`, or `baz` are given. Is there a better way to express this within Haskell's type system?

**Note**: Unfortunately I am unable to make this separate requests. I'm just following a defined protocol.

Comment: What are `foo`, `bar` and `baz`? What is the relation between these three?

Comment: They are different types of 'impressions' that can come into the service. `Banner`, `Video`, `Native`. They each describe a different kind of impression that can be bid on. I'm trying to implement the OpenRTB spec in Haskell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a canonical haskell type for "One or Both"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413438/is-there-a-canonical-haskell-type-for-one-or-both)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.4.2/docs/Data-These.html

```
import Data.These
data A = A
  { id :: Integer
  , fooBarBaz :: These Foo (These Bar Baz)
  }

type Foo = String
type Bar = String
type Baz = String
```

Comment: Perhaps include a brief explanation instead of just code and a reference link.

Comment: No, it's exactly how it should be.

Comment: There is also a minimalist version of `These` in [`data-or`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-or).

Comment: This would probably work for my case, but is there another solution that would work better for the case of have 4,5,...,N number of fields that could be in the value?

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `Map Field String` with `data Field = Foo | Bar | Baz` (this can easily be replaced with `String` if needed, and then have:

```
data A = A
    { id :: Integer
    , fields :: Map Field String
    }
```

Now checking for the validity condition is as simple as:

```
isValid :: A -> Bool
isValid = not . Map.null . fields
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is not mandatory to have three separate fields with foo,bar and baz, I'd go with this, [NonEmpty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/NonEmptyList-0.0.9/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) guarantees that there is at least one element, though there can of course be more.

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty

data Impression = Banner String | Video String | Native String

data A = A
  { id :: Integer
  , fooBarBaz :: NonEmpty Impression
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ's suggestion to use a map: [there's also a type specifically for non-empty maps](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/non-empty-0.2.1/docs/Data-NonEmpty-Map.html). (Note however that this sort of clashes with the more popular nonempty-list type [from the `semigroups` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.16.2.2/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html).)

```
import qualified Data.NonEmpty.Map as NEM

data Field = Foo | Bar | Baz
data A = A { id :: Integer
           , fields :: NEM.T Field String
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider giving one branch for each possible required field:

```
data A
    = Foo
        { foo :: String
        , barM, bazM :: Maybe String
        }
    | Bar
        { bar :: String
        , fooM, barM :: Maybe String
        }
    | Baz
        { baz :: String
        , fooM, barM :: Maybe String
        }
```

It's a fair bit of boilerplate, but it's very direct and quite clear about what's required.